# finding memory leak using dottrace

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I have a SW that communicate with a controller (using modbus) and logs data.
After 5 minutes the SW memory size is 50Mb and after 20 minutes it reaches 70Mb and after 7 days it riches 800Mb and usually crashed.
I have been advice to use DotTrace SW to find the memory leak. I did.
I have the reports but I don't know how to read them.
Is there anyoמe who can read this and tell me where is the problem?
It seems that the SW memory is only around 10Mb but in the Windows task manager it writes 80Mb (give or take).

Here is a link to the report
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0wvqalup6rlpe6w/mTEWGReanb

Thanks in advance

Comment: An external link to a document that only DotTrace users can open makes this off-topic for SO. Post the relevant screenshos or ask at the jetBrains fora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found this...
It helped me solve the problem.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/2016.3/How_to_Find_a_Memory_Leak.html

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/2016.2/Get_Started_with_Performance_Viewer.html if you want dotTrace